# SocketChannel in Android

Tags: android, sockets, connect, ioexception, socketchannel

I have a question about SocketChannels in Android. This is my code:

```
SocketChannel socketChannel = SocketChannel.open();
socketChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 90));
```

This code works in Java but not in Android. I always get an IOException My first problem was the first line. I had to add permissions to open sockets. The first line now works but the second line doesn't. I always get an IOException.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

127.0.0.1? you try to connect to your android device with socket 90. I don't think your device has open up such port for your program to connect.

Answer (score 0):

try opening the socket on the physical device.  your probably running it on the emulator and that port isnt opened.